# Borderlands Pre-Sequel - Number of possible weapons

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I remember an old advert for the original Borderlands about how there were a "Bajillion" different guns you could find. Obviously this was for marketing purposes. (According to Gearbox the first Borderlands had 17,750,000 and Borderlands 2 had "many more" with a wider variety)

My question: How many different variations of guns are there in Borderlands the Pre-Sequel?

Comment: I'm kind of upset with that I have lots of work and family duties now, and can't just sit down, dust off my combinatorics math skills and straight up calculate the answer. Almost all the data can be found in this [thread on Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=343943054&insideModal=1)...

Comment: @OrcJMR Perfect, exactly the link I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also some information on other weapon properties on [this Wiki page](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Borderlands_2_Weapons)

Comment: Example calculation: number of possible Assault Rifles, not counting levels, elements, and Uniques/Legendaries (these are few anyway): there are 7 barrels (one e-tech), 5 grips, 5 stocks, 6 scopes (including none), 5 bodies, and 8 accessories (including none). Now, considering common items don't roll accessory, and purple always have accessory, we have: white: 6x5x5x6x5x1 + green+blue (2x)6x5x5x6x5x8 + purple+e-tech 7x5x5x6x5x7 = 113 250 Assault Rifles.

Answer (score -1):

A weapon is build with:
-body
-barrel
-stock
-Magazine
-Barrel
-Sight
-Accessory

[The Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_Rifle/parts) has a good article about the mechanical composition of a combat rifle.

The number you are searching for is the sum of all possible builds, which increased dramatically with the new weapons (Laser-Shotgun, -Railgun, -Beam) and the new element (Cryo).

Hope I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

A gun in Borderlands are made overall using a randomzing algorithm including some other things, that's the reason there are so many guns (the developers can't possibly make that amount of guns obviously).

Basically put, a set number is not something you can find through the internet, especially when you consider there is a case of the SAME gun having different stats on it.

The numbers definitely didn't increase drastically from each game to another, they did increase but not **majorly** so.

So overall, there isn't a document on the internet that will give you the correct number, however it's definitely more than the 17.7mil that borderlands 1 had. Borderlands 2 most likely increased the count with only 2-3 million due the new elements. If you are a very hardcore fan that collected a lot of guns from Borderlands 1 you will realize many basic ideas of every model carried over (if not most)... The Pre Sequel does mostly the same (especially with Jakob guns)